# Поиск наибольшей подстроки в строке

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Задача: даны две строки S и T. Нужно найти их общую подстроку наибольшей длины. По условиям обе строки имеют одинаковую длину L (1≤L≤100000) и состоят только из строчных латинских букв. Гарантируется, что строки имеют хотя бы одну общую букву.

Я решил следующим образом:

```
var s = Console.ReadLine();
var t = Console.ReadLine();
var best = string.Empty;
for (int start = 0; start < s.Length; start++)
for (int length = 1; start + length <= s.Length; length++)
{
    var substring = s.Substring(start, length);
    if (t.Contains(substring) && substring.Length > best.Length)
        best = substring;
}
Console.WriteLine(best);
```

Но есть проблема - это неэффективно. Как можно сделать по-другому? Например, используя linq или же убрать один внешний цикл. Я плох в алгоритмах, а в гугле только такое решение.

Comment: https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D1%81_%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC_%D1%85%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F плюс две ссылки в "См. также".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение по алгоритму с использованием хеширования, [по ссылке](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D1%81_%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC_%D1%85%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) от @Akina, будет выглядеть примерно так.

```
static string LargestCommonSubstring(string left, string right)
{
    if (left == right) 
        return left;

    for (int length = left.Length - 1; length > 1; length--)
    {
        HashSet<string> set = new();
        for (int offset = 0; offset <= left.Length - length; offset++)
        {
            set.Add(left.Substring(offset, length));
        }
        for (int offset = 0; offset <= right.Length - length; offset++)
        {
            string substring = right.Substring(offset, length);
            if (set.Contains(substring))
                return substring;
        }
    }

    // оптимизация для односимвольной подстроки
    char[] chars = left.Distinct().OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
    foreach (char c in right)
    {
        if (Array.BinarySearch(chars, c) >= 0)
            return c.ToString();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: `будет выглядеть примерно так` Если не ошибаюсь, здесь хэши считаются за квадратичное время, а эффективное решение подразумевает rolling хэш. И проверка всех длин тоже не фонтан - итого получается куб вместо nlogn

Comment: @MBo к сожалению, я не вижу пути решить это эффективнее используя только .NET классы. Если бы реально нужна была производительность, я бы использовал спаны и векторы и что-то получше полного перебора, например идти на увеличение и каждую последующую подстроку, которая длиннее на 1 символ искал бы среди найденных предыдущих, используя их как префиксы или что-то подобное. Что-то типа индексации, не уверен как это финально может выглядеть. Так что можно считать, что хэширование - это просто, но не лучшее решение, на мой взгляд.